# Crop the current touch point on a UIScrollView and display it in a UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit, crop

I'm working on a drawing feature. I need the user to be able to see what is being drawn under their finger. The photo is inside of a `UIScrollView`. I basically just want to crop the area around the current pointer location and display it in a separate view at the top of the screen. The following GIF is from Android and shows the behavior I want to implement (see the circular region at the top, which I call the "zoomer" window):

[image: Here's the effect I want to achieve]

I'm having trouble implementing this in iOS. The following code is my attempt to implement this zoomer window as a rectangle:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: zoomerWindowWidth, height: zoomerWindowWidth), false, 0)
let cropRect = CGRect(
        x: -(lastPointTouched.x - zoomerWindowWidth / 2),
        y: -(lastPointTouched.y + zoomerWindowWidth / 2),
        width: view.bounds.size.width,
        height: view.bounds.size.height
)

mainScrollView.drawHierarchy(in: cropRect, afterScreenUpdates: true)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
zoomerImageView.image = image
```

This almost works, but the current touch point doesn't stay centered in the zoomer window. And when the `UIScrollView` is zoomed in or out, the window gets even more out of alignment. My attempts to multiply by a scale factor have all failed.

Here's what it currently looks like:

[image: What it currently looks like]

TLDR: I need the little window to stay centered on the current touch location. Can anyone help?

Here's the full codebase: https://github.com/gavingt/ios_draw_zoom . See [here](https://github.com/gavingt/ios_draw_zoom/blob/4957599cfedbdb0bafe7f85b72969c37c2bf7459/Sources/General/ZLEditImageViewController.swift#L403) in particular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [friendly Redditor](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/160d7y2/how_to_crop_an_area_around_the_current_touch/) found the solution:

```
let lastPointTouched = view.convert(self.lastPointTouched, from: drawingImageView)
let cropRect = CGRect(
        x: -(lastPointTouched.x - zoomerWindowWidth / 2),
        y: -(lastPointTouched.y - zoomerWindowWidth/2 ),
        width: view.bounds.size.width,
        height: view.bounds.size.height
)
```

You can also check the latest Github commit for the working version.